# needed: simple way to force json to decode to "normal" iterable python lists

Tags: python, json, list, unicode, iterable

I've stackoverflow a ton and never found the need to ask a question before, and while there are a lot of threads on this subject, I can't seem to find something that is easy and makes sense.  If I have somehow missed something, please provide a link.

Here goes:  I am trying to pass lists back and forth between a python client/server using json, but am condensing the problem into a single block to illustrate:

```
import json
testdata = ['word','is','bond', False, 6, 99]
# prints normal iterable list
print testdata

myjson = json.dumps(testdata)

#prints [u'word', u'is', u'bond', False, 6, 99], which contains unicode strings
print json.loads(myjson)

# Iterates over each character, since apparently, Python does recognize it is a list
for i in myjson:
    print i
```

This seems wrong.  I passed in an iterable list, and I got out something that can't be used that way.  I've seen a lot of answers that suggest that I should just "deal with unicode" which is fine, if I knew how.  Either I need a way to force json to load as ascii or utf-8 or something, or a way to allow python to iterate normally over the list containing unicode strings normally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're iterating over `myjson`, the string, not over the result of `json.loads(myjson)`, the iterable list.

```
myjson = json.dumps(testdata)

mydata = json.loads(myjson)
#prints [u'word', u'is', u'bond', False, 6, 99], which contains unicode strings
print mydata
#prints ["word", "is", "bond", false, 6, 99], which is still just a string
print myjson

# Iterates over each character, since it's a string
for i in myjson:
    print i
# Iterates over the list
for i in mydata:
    print i
```

Comment: Ok, it works - that is really simple.  I hate that my first question was so stupid.

Comment: @domoarrigato: Stupid questions are _exactly_ the ones you can't figure out for yourself, because they're so obvious you don't notice them. I was here answering your question because I was taking a break from a `"abc", "def" "ghi", "jkl"` type bug that I stared at for half an hour before a coworker spotted it immediately…

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps(testdata)` is giving you a string... so iterating over the string gives you individual characters. Your code is doing exactly what you're asking it to do.

`json.loads` does **not** perform an in-place modification of the variable - so `myjson` is still a string when you iterate over it.

Comment: abarnert was a bit faster - Thanks!